# Does Flink have the rate source that Spark has?

Tags: apache-flink

In Spark there's the rate source, which is used for testing.

So, you do:

```
val df = spark.readStream
  .format("rate")
  .option("rowsPerSecond", 10)
  .load()
```

And it produces an unbounded stream of records for testing. Does Flink have anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it has the DataGen connector for the Table API:

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/datagen/

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/common/

Comment: +1 for DataGen: if you want meaningful data, you can also consider the Flink Faker connector https://github.com/knaufk/flink-faker